# Haskell throws a parse error in a strange place

Tags: haskell, parse-error

A toy example but still frustrating:

```
numberMapper:: IO ()
numberMapper = do codes <- forM [1 .. 4] (\num ->
                   do putStrLn $ "Enter a code for " ++ show num
                       code <- getLine
                       return code)
                   let numberCodes = zip [1 .. 4] codes
                   in forM numberCodes (\(num,code) ->
                   putStrLn $ "Got code " ++ show code ++ " for " ++ show num)
```

`ghci` tells me I have a `Parse error in pattern: putStrLn` and I can't figure out why it should fail to parse.

Comment: Ok, this works if I add braces for the do blocks and semicolons at the end of each 'statement' -- but is that the recommended solution ?
(it seems a little un-functional :P)

Comment: You can pretend that the semicolons and braces are already there, but invisible.  (There are rules for where the automatic braces and semicolons go.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Correction:

```
numberMapper:: IO ()
numberMapper = do
    codes <- forM [1 .. 4] $ \num -> do
        putStrLn $ "Enter a code for " ++ show num
        getLine
    let numberCodes = zip [1 .. 4] codes
    forM_ numberCodes $ \(num,code) ->
        putStrLn $ "Got code " ++ show code ++ " for " ++ show num
```

**Fix:** The lines inside a `do` block should line up.

```
-- wrong
a = do codes <- something
        let numberCodes = zip [1..4] codes

-- right
a = do codes <- something
       let numberCodes = zip [1..4] codes
```

**Fix 2:** When using `let` inside a `do` block, don't use `in`.

```
-- wrong
func = do
    let x = 17
    in print x

-- right
func = do
    let x = 17
    print x
```

**Fix 3:** Use `forM_` (which returns `()`, a.k.a. void) instead of `forM` (which returns a list).

```
codes <- forM [1..4] func...  -- returns a list
forM_ numberCodes $ ...       -- discards list, returns ()
```

So `forM_` could (almost) be written like this:

```
forM_ xs f = do forM xs f
                return ()
```

**Minor change:** You don't need `return` here:

```
do func1
   x <- func2
   return x
```

You can change it to the equivalent,

```
do func1
   func2 -- value of func2 is returned
```

Answer (score 4):

You over-indent lines in your do-blocks.  Furthermore, you don't need an `in` for `let` statements in `do`-blocks.

This works for me:

```
numberMapper:: IO ()
numberMapper = do codes <- forM [1 .. 4] (\num ->
                   do putStrLn $ "Enter a code for " ++ show num
                      code <- getLine
                      return code)
                  let numberCodes = zip [1 .. 4] codes
                  forM numberCodes (\(num,code) ->
                    putStrLn $ "Got code " ++ show code ++ " for " ++ show num)
```

You can also structure it like this:

```
numberMapper:: IO ()
numberMapper = do codes <- forM [1 .. 4] $ \num ->
                   do putStrLn $ "Enter a code for " ++ show num
                      code <- getLine
                      return code
                  let numberCodes = zip [1 .. 4] codes
                  forM numberCodes $ \(num,code) ->
                    putStrLn $ "Got code " ++ show code ++ " for " ++ show num
```

(which lets you avoid the parentheses; alternatively, put the `do` at the end of the `\num ->` and line up subsequent statements)